# Xcode Today Extension stuck on "Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, today-extension

i'am trying to add an app extension to my project (Today Extension).

Things that i've made so far:

1. Enable "App Groups" from both main application and extension capabilities.
2. Checked that both targets "Team" profiles are valid. (even deleted them from provisioning portal and let xcode to receated them)
3. Checked from provisioning portal that both app id's have correct groups selected.
4. Deleted everything from provisioning portal, and receated everthing through xcode.

Everything looks ok, both targets have "app groups" enabled and selected same app group id's, and no error visible.

btw. I 've tried both on normal and beta (6.2) versions of xcode. Still no luck..

Comment: I get the same error but still my share extension works (and was approved by Apple). So maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Wow, after you've told that ur app works, i've checked my app and realized that i can share data between my app and extension. Thanks!

Comment: @dasdom please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it... The error seems to be some kind of bug. Everything works normal despite the error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I get the same error but still my share extension works (and was approved by Apple). So maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, i realized that the error shows, but everything works fine. (I was using nsuserdefaults for sharing data)

Comment: Same thing for iMessage App Extensions. It would fail trying to debug them but works otherwise.

Comment: @Rivera I have same problem, did you fixed it ? If yes how you did it ?